# Access Class Variable in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class defined as:

```
class Constants
{
   public static string settingsToolTip = "Settings";
}
```

I want to set this string for a tooltip of a button like:

```
<Button Name= "ButtonSettingsWindow" ToolTip="Settings" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2000"/>
```

Instead of hardcoding the string "Settings" in XAML, I want it to use the string from Constants class. How can i do this in WPF XAML?

Comment: Have a static property and Bind it to the `ToolTip`...

Comment: The XAML file is already a localizable resource that can be edited independently of the compiled source code. Why would you want to build this dependency in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access static members of class using **[x:Static markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** in XAML.

```
<Button ToolTip="{x:Static local:Constants.settingsToolTip}"/>
```

Make sure you have added namespace in XAML file (*local*) where Constant class is declared:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ActualNameSpace"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is binding.

Example:

Code behind:

```
 class Test
{
    public string test { get { return "Settings"; } }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <y:Test></y:Test>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding test}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

The result is a button that says "Settings" :)

Comment: Note that you can not use this to bind to the Window class